# Exception while getting path in JBOSS but working fine in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, jboss

Getting exception for below code in `JBOSS` but it is working fine in `Tomcat`

```
File path = new File(MyServlet.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());
```

Exception:

```
exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI scheme is not "file"
```

What is there in `JBOSS` which is giving me above exception but working fine in `Tomcat`, and what is the alternate to get path of `MyServlet` Class

Comment: It is a very vague assumption that there is even a physical location for some class in J2EE world, as it largely depends how some particular server implements deployment. What is the point of knowing the "location" of that servlet class?

Comment: @GyroGearless I have kept some configuration files on the package where `MyServlet` is present

Comment: You'll have more luck loading the configuration files with something like `MyServlet.class.getResourceAsStream(...)`.